# How to make a foreign key from a composite key?

Tags: mysql, ddl

I want to make a foreign key from a primary key and got this error '#1005 - Can't create table'

Here is the DDL used...

```
CREATE TABLE Invoice
(
InvoiceID SMALLINT,
TaskID SMALLINT,
FOREIGN KEY Invoice(InvoiceID) REFERENCES XTABLE(InvoiceID),
PRIMARY KEY (InvoiceID, TaskID)
);
```

Comment: Is this the entire error message? Did you try FOREIGN KEY InoviceID instead of FOREIGN KEY Invoice(InvoiceID)? Or maybe write REFERENCES XTABLE(InvoiceID) directly after InvoiceID SMALLINT?

Comment: Show `CREATE TABLE XTABLE ...`

Comment: The question title mentions a composite key but your foreign key only uses one column: `InvoiceID` :-?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the key columns in `XTABLE` and `Invoice` are marked as the `PRIMARY KEY` and `NOT NULL`.

```
CREATE TABLE XTABLE(InvoiceID SMALLINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(InvoiceID));

CREATE TABLE Invoice ( 
  InvoiceID SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
  TaskID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (InvoiceID, TaskID),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY Invoice(InvoiceID) REFERENCES XTABLE(InvoiceID)
);
```

**SQL FIDDLE:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a56f